# How to access root files in atom to be able to modify them

Tags: atom-editor

The problem is that when using atom as an editor, to access a root file according to the documentation, the shortcut is cmd-shift-h, but this does not work for me. Is there a special shortcut for mac? or another way to access these files.

I tried with cmd-shift-h but it does not work on my mac.
The other thing is in the terminal sudo route, but I do not have the exact path of webpacker.config.js.

```
The cmd-shift-h shortcut on my mac does not work
```

Comment: I replaced your tags because your question has nothing to do with Ruby, Rails, or webpack. I recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging, and while you’re at it you should read the entire help center and take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour before posting.

Comment: It would be helpful to add a link to the part of the documentation where you found this. I also don't see any commands exposed to the mentioned shortcut (see the *Key Bind Resolver* command in Atom). Lastly, when I try to save a file (e.g. `/etc/hosts`) that requires elevated rights, Atom simply asks me for my password prior to saving.